# What is "gps on demand time injection"

Tags: gps, android

Android defineds a GPS device capability I couldn't find reference to
It's defined as GPS_CAPABILITY_ON_DEMAND_TIME in [gps.h](http://www.openfoundry.org/svn/nsc102rvsp/HAL_Interface/include/hardware/gps.h) 
The description in the comment explains:
GPS on demand time injection.
What does it mean ?

Answer (score 2):

`GPS_CAPABILITY_ON_DEMAND_TIME` refers to the ability of the Android framework to trigger an injection of the current time into the GPS engine.  This is used as part of the assistance data to speed up time-to-first-fix.  Here's where the constant is used in the Android framework:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/location/GpsLocationProvider.java#L1625

You can see what happens in the `handleInjectNtpTime()` method (NTP = "Network Time Protocol"):
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/location/GpsLocationProvider.java#L842

Apps can also trigger this via the `LocationManager.sendExtraCommand("force_time_injection");` method - the app [GPSTest](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.gpstest) has a button where you can trigger this time injection manually, if you want to hook up an Android device and trigger the call and see what happens (fully disclosure - GPSTest is my app).  On some devices you can see LogCat output fetching the NTP time.

Here's the code in GPSTest that triggers the call to inject NTP time:
https://github.com/barbeau/gpstest/blob/master/GPSTest/src/main/java/com/android/gpstest/GpsTestActivity.java#L173